# Adding two right bar button items to the navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a navigation bar to which I have added right BarButton successfully. Both the NavigationBar and BarButton are created programmatically. Now according to my requirement I got to add two right BarButtons to my navigation Bar. Can anyone tell me how to do this? My app is targeting ios4.

Answer (score 15):

This code will do the trick for you,

```
 NSArray *barButtonItems= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.addButton,self.sortbyButton,nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems=barButtonItems;
```

where addButton and sortbyButton are 2 separate BarButton Items

Comment: self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems  is working from IOS 5 onwards. It is not going to work for IOS 4.My app is targeting IOS 4

Answer (score 2):

I know it is too late but I faced it recently. So here is what I did
Create a UIView in code and add the buttons as subviews into this view. 
Create a ToolbarButton using [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttons]

Assign this toolbar button as the Left or right barbuttonItem as U wish.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation to `UINavigationItem`[1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UINavigationItem) describes, it has a property `rightBarButtonItems` (as well as `leftBarButtonItems`) where you can give an array of `UIBarButtons`. They are display from right (index 0) to left (index n-1).

Comment: I have clearly specified that my app is targeting IOS 4.  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems is working from IOS 5 onwards

Comment: @user1626799: IOS5 came up March 2012. `rightBarButtonItems`exist since October 2011 (at least, if the revision docu is correct)

Comment: @Matthais:I have tested it and its not working in IOS 4. So as far as I know its not working in IOS 4. U can also follow up the comment below by BornCoder

Comment: @user1626799: My mistake, the early date was the pre-version for IOS 5.

Comment: @Matthais:oh okay.Can you tell me how to achieve my task in IOS 4

Answer (score 0):

If you application is targeting iOS 4 and above then you should take UISegmentControl and have two segments on it. Catch value changed action event and check which segment is selected and do you operation accordingly.

You can also set images to segments to make look and feel better.

Comment: Can you please give an example

Answer (score 0):

@Matthias, As stated in documentation, **rightBarButtonItems** property is available from iOS 5 and above and this function needs to be supported also on iOS 4.

So, UISegmentControl is best way to achieve this.

Comment: can you please give me an example on how to use UISegmentControl to achieve my task .

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *segmentTextContent = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               NSLocalizedString(@\"Group By\", @\"\"),
                               NSLocalizedString(@\"Filter By\", @\"\"),
                               nil];
UISegmentedcontrol *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentTextContent];
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
segmentedControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 125, 30);
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleUnit) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
defaultTintColor = [segmentedControl.tintColor retain];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = segmentedControl;
[segmentedControl release];
```

Comment: I have achieved my task by using tool bar, instead of the Segmented control

Comment: You mean to say you replaced whole navigationbar with toolbar. is it? Or you added toolbar to UINavigationBar ?

Comment: I added the toolbar to the navigation bar